# Insert/Update SQL queries for decimal separator comma in NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, delphi-xe, nls-lang

I need to create bulk insert/update queries for which it is necessary to pass ORACLE SQL queries in string format, and I cannot use parametrized queries, because of some performance issue in SQL query string parsing in Delphi.

My concern is, while creating these queries and passing float values, should I be concerned about the NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS of the Database? For now I am passing my queries as:

```
   "INSERT ALL
    INTO TABLE EMPLOYEE (EMP_ID, EMP_SAL) VALUES (123, 123.123)
    INTO TABLE EMPLOYEE (EMP_ID, EMP_SAL) VALUES (345, 345.345)
    INTO TABLE EMPLOYEE (EMP_ID, EMP_SAL) VALUES (456, 456.456)
    SELECT * FROM DUAL"
```

Should I read the value of NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS instead and then fire the following bulk query if decimal separator is ',', or is this handled by the DB server?

```
   "INSERT ALL
    INTO TABLE EMPLOYEE (EMP_ID, EMP_SAL) VALUES (123, '123,123')
    INTO TABLE EMPLOYEE (EMP_ID, EMP_SAL) VALUES (345, '345,345')
    INTO TABLE EMPLOYEE (EMP_ID, EMP_SAL) VALUES (456, '456,456')
    SELECT * FROM DUAL"
```

How should the implementation be for SQL server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS is only used when converting strings (`varchar`) to numbers or numbers to strings. It doesn't matter if the conversion is implicit (as in your second example) or explicit when using `to_char()` or `to_number()`.

Plain SQL number literals (=constants) **always** use the `.` as the decimal separator. A number like `123.123` will always be treated correctly regardless of the value of NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS - this is also true for SQL Server.

It's not clear to me what you mean with "*the implementation be for SQL server*". If it's about the insert statement inserting more than a single row, then the equivalent in SQL Server (and standard SQL) would be:

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE 
  (EMP_ID, EMP_SAL) 
VALUES 
  (123, 123.123),
  (345, 345.345),
  (456, 456.456);
```

Comment: Ok. That answers my question. Thanks! By SQL server implementation, I meant if such decimal separator manipulation has to be done there too. But this answers my query.